# Show that $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z} \cup \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$ is not simply connected

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

I am trying to prove that $E=\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z} \cup \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{R}$ isn't simply connected. I tried something, but I got something wrong. This is what I had thought: if I act on $E$ with integer translations on both axis, that is with the group $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, I have a properly discontinuous action. The quotient space (let's say the projection is $p$) should be the sides of a square. Then I should have (since $E$ is connected) that $\frac{\pi_1 ( \text{square})}{p_{*}(\pi_1 (E))}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$, where $p_{*}$ is the inducted homomorphism of $p$. Now, it is obvious that the fundamental group of the square is $\mathbb{Z}$, but then something doesn't work, because I have that the quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: The quotient is actually rather isomorphic to two circles joined at one point ("8")

Comment: Would you clarify the order of operations in the first sentence if they aren't meant to be performed in sequential order?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor the elements of the group I was refferring to would act like $(x,y) \to (x+m,x+n)$ with $m,n$ integers. I don't understand what you mean by "performed in sequential order"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yeah indeed, I just thought that points at one side are identified with those at the other. So $p_{*}(\pi_1(E))$ would be the subgroup of commutators of $\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}$ and since $p_{*}$ can be proven be injective, I can conclude that $\pi_1 (E)$ is isomorphic to the subgroup of commutator of the free product of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your space is not simply-connected because it contains the boundary of the square$$\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2\,|\,x\in\{0,1\}\vee y\in\{0,1\}\},$$but no point of its interior.

Comment: Yeah, in fact this would have been enough. In one of the comments I have tried to give an answer, check it out if you want!